# What is the use case of using XOR with 1 in the comparator operator of priority_queue C++

Tags: bitwise-operators, priority-queue, bitwise-xor

From "the cppreference" example of STL priority_queue in C++ [(link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), I don't fully understand the last example given there.
The comparator is a lambda expression, which is all fine & well, but then the usage of the bitwise XOR there with 1 for each of the arguments is something that I don't get - what is it good for?

Here is the code example:

```
auto cmp = [](int left, int right) { return (left ^ 1) < (right ^ 1);};
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> q3(cmp);

for(int n : {1,8,5,6,3,4,0,9,7,2})
    q3.push(n);

print_queue(q3);



template<typename T> void print_queue(T& q) {
    while(!q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.top() << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
8 9 6 7 4 5 2 3 0 1
```

I can see that the result is that the vector is sorted in pairs, in which the second is greater than the first one, but I don't fully understand 2 things:

1. How XOR-ing with 1 gets this effect? (I have a sense there, that toggling the first bit is making it to relate to 8 as greater than 9 and then 7 greater than 6, etc.)
2. What is the use case/application for such ordering?

Comment: [`8 ^ 1` (`0b00001000 ^ 0b00000001`) is `9` (`0b00001001`), and `9 ^ 1` (`0b00001001 ^ 0b00000001`) is `8` (`0b00001000`).](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/465158833c95d3a3)  It's just flipping the "odd number" bit before comparing.

Comment: Thanks! and what about the use cases of such comparator?